# Send an xml file using Java code than get that file in python web service. Than change nothing and send it to google cloud

Tags: python, java, google-cloud-storage

This is my first time to ask a question here and i hope to find an answer.

I wrote a code using Java to send an xml file to a pointed web service written in Python.  when i make the request, I got a 405 Error, which says that the file format is not supported.

My goal is to send this file to the python web service, than send it to google cloud using same python web service.

Why not sending the file directly to google cloud? Yes i got it. but i have a portal where to a user can access the xml file.

Thank you for any valuable answer how to receive the xml file using this python web service and send it to google cloud.

This is the Java code i am using to send the file and it works just fine.

```
    public void sendFileToWebservice(String url, String result) {   
 
 try {

 URL obj = new URL(url);
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
 con.setRequestMethod("POST");
 con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");

 con.setDoOutput(true);
 DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
 wr.writeBytes(result);
 wr.flush();
 wr.close();
 String responseStatus = con.getResponseMessage();
 System.out.println(responseStatus);
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
 con.getInputStream()));
 String inputLine;
 StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
 response.append(inputLine);
 }
 in.close();
 System.out.println("response:" + response.toString());
 } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println(e);
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a DataOutputStream here? I don't think this is what you want. Look at the API doc. "Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits.". You should use an OutputStreamWriter with UTF-8 encoding instead.

Comment: And please: Indent your code. It is not really readable at the current state.